# Prove that a connected graph with minimal degree 2 has at least 1 edge which isn't a bridge.

Tags: graph-theory

Bridge = an edge that connects between 2 connectivity components, where removing it will divide the graph into 2 separate connectivity components.

Comment: Hint: think of the class of graphs where every edge is a bridge

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: @anomaly I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Well, try something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit:* I just realised I skimmed over the hypothesis that $G$ is connected; it is not necessary. Adjust your reading of the answer to follow accordingly.

This is nearly trivial, but here is a proof template that will hopefully not only help you for this problem, but get you thinking about some basic results in graph theory.

First, recall that a tree is a connected, **acyclic** graph, and a forest is a graph whose components are all trees (i.e. any old acyclic graph). You've probably heard the following before: Every tree $T$ of order at least 2 has at least 2 *leaves* (also known as pendant vertices, or simply vertices of degree 1). If this isn't familiar to you, prove it yourself (it is straightforward; as a hint, consider a longest path in $T$).

Since your graph has $\delta(G) = 2$, it does not have any degree-1 vertices. Justify to yourself that this means the graph in question is **not** a forest, i.e., that it has cycles.

Now, let $C$ be any cycle in your graph. Another very early result (at least when I learned graph theory) is that an edge $e$ is a cut-edge (also known as a bridge) if and only if $e$ belongs to no cycle (again, please justify this for yourself; one direction is immediate, and the other isn't much more work). Since we've decided that our graph $G$ contains a cycle $C$, pick $e$ to be any edge on $C$. Applying the (contrapositive of) the result from earlier in this paragraph, we see that the chosen edge is not a bridge. This concludes your problem.

**Remarks:** Obviously this technique isn't the only one (and isn't the simplest argument), but it proves something stronger than what you've asked (can you see why?) and hopefully has some pedagogical value to you as you start formulating your basic graph theory toolkit. Hope this has helped.